# Using MEF with dependency injection

Tags: c#, mef

I have a class that is instantiated using dependency injection of a logger type like so:

```
var _logger = Logger.GetLogger(LoggerType.MongoLogger);         
var service = new MyService(_logger);
```

in my unit tests, I replace the logger to use:

```
var _logger = Logger.GetLogger(LoggerType.TextFileLogger);
```

Now, I want to use MEF to load MyService as a plugin I created the service like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IService))]
    public class MyService: IService
    {
        private ILogger _logger;    

        public MyService(ILogger  logger)
        {
            this._logger = logger;
        }
        public void DoServiceWork()
        {
            _logger.Log("Starting service work");
        }
    }
```

How do I make this thing work in the MEF framework ?

Answer (score 3):

Edited:
Added more elaborate example, using a console app.

### Bootstrap Class

This class creates the MEF container as well as initializes the aggregate catalog. You should also instantiate other exportable items, e.g. ILogger, which be used by other dependent classes in your program. Creating properties and marking them with `Export` allows these instances to be used throughout your program.

You should only instantiate this class once. In this example, we instantiate it in the main program block at the startup.

We have marked both `Container` and `ILogger` as exports as we want these instances to be available to other dependent classes.

### Exporting IService

Marking your MySerivce class with Export(IService) allows it to be exportable in MEF. We use MEF to get an instance of it by calling `Container.GetExportedValue<IService>();`. Note: by default MEF will use singleton shared instance, i.e. object will be created once. If you want non-shared instances, you will have to mark classes with `PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)`

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        var service = bootstrap.Container.GetExportedValue<IService>();
        service.DoServiceWork();
    }


}

public class Bootstrap
{
    [Export]
    public CompositionContainer Container { get; private set; }

    [Export(typeof(ILogger))]
    public ILogger Logger { get; private set; }

    public  Bootstrap()
    {
        //Create an aggregate catalog that will hold assembly references
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

        //Adds this assembly. 
        //Exports defined in the classes and types within this assembly will now be composable
        //Add to the catalogs if there are more assemblies where exports are defined.
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

        //Create the CompositionContainer with the parts in the catalog
        this.Container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        this.Logger = Logger.GetLogger(LoggerType.MongoLogger);
        this.Container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}

[Export(typeof(IService))]
public class MyService : IService
{

    //adding pragma directive removes compiler warning of unassigned property/field
    //as these will be assigned by MEF import 
#pragma warning disable

    [Import]
    private ILogger _logger;

#pragma warning restore


    public MyService()
    {
        //logger will be instantiated by MEF
    }

    public void DoServiceWork()
    {
        _logger.Log("Starting service work");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this, I am not sure I am following what SomeInitClass is, and how my Logger will be injected into MyService.

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: In my scenario, I need to instantiate MyService with the logger type in its c-tor, the logger is injected to MyService through the ctor, in many cases, the logger type is different for different instances of MyService.
In your scenario, the logger is instantiated insode the bootstrap, and it's "hard coded" tp be MongoLogger for EVERY instance of MyService.

Comment: That is a different use case, and this solution can be changed to support what you are asking. Your original question was how to inject logger instance, which I think I have answered. If I have time I will update the answer.

Comment: I dont think you answered the question, your solution moves the creation of the logger from inside the object to the MEF framework, it still very much coupled, the whole notion of injection is to not rely on implementation, rather than on type.